# ¿Como puedo insertar una imagen en html que llame a una función php para cambiar de idioma?

Tags: php, html, css, img

Tenía un desplegable para seleccionar el idioma y quería 
sustituirlo por imágenes que al clicar en ellas cambiasen el idioma:

[image: banderas españa y reino unido]

Tengo el siguiente script en php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$idioma = $_POST['idioma'];
$_SESSION['idioma'] = $idioma;
header('Location:' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

Y estana intentando algo como esto:

```
<form action="../Functions/CambioIdioma.php" method="post">
                    <input type="image" src="../View/Icons/spain_flag_icon.jpg" width="25" height="15" name="idiomaform" value="SPANISH" id="boton1" onclick = "../Functions/CambioIdioma.php">
                    <input type="image" src="../View/Icons/uk_flag_icon.png" width="25" height="15" name="idiomaform" value="ENGLISH" id="boton1" 
                    onclick ="../Functions/CambioIdioma.php">
</form>
```

Se muestran las imágenes pero al hacer click no cambia el idioma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento onclick ejecuta funciones de javascript por lo que no ejecutaría el script de PHP que colocas dentro del evento. 
La solución a como lo planteas seria de la siguiente manera

```
<form action="../Functions/CambioIdioma.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="idiomaform" value="SPANISH"/>
        <button type="submit"><img src="../View/Icons/spain_flag_icon.jpg" alt="Espa&ntilde;ol"></button>
</form>
<form action="../Functions/CambioIdioma.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="idiomaform" value="ENGLISH"/>
    <button type="submit"><img src="../View/Icons/uk_flag_icon.png" alt="Ingl&eacute;s"></button>
</form>
```

Ahora en el script de PHP no estas obteniendo el valor de de los formularios, ya que en la variable $idioma obtiene de $_POST un valor que no esta definido, ya que en el formulario de das del nombre de "idiomaform" por lo que la manera correcta seria

```
<?php
session_start();
$idioma = 'SPANISH';
if(isset($_POST['idiomaform']))
    $idioma = $_POST['idiomaform'];
$_SESSION['idioma'] = $idioma;
header('Location:' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

De esta manera definimos un idioma por defecto y nos aseguramos que el valor 'idiomaform' este definido dentro de $_POST.

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente. Al final introduje los formularios en una tabla para que se me muestren en horizontal y tengo justamente lo que quería, muchas gracias.